# Changing GIMP's default startup option

Tags: 12.10, gimp, maximized

When I open GIMP, I would like it to appear in maximized single-window mode.  Is there a way I can do this, either with a shell script or preferences option?

Answer (score 2):

If yours is Gimp>=2.8.2, which it most likely is in Ubuntu 12.10, You can simply select

```
Windows > Single Window mode
```

and you will get gimp in single window mode the next time.

As for keeping it maximised, install [maximus](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/maximus) from Ubuntu Software Centre.

```
sudo apt-get install maximus
```

Now run

```
maximus
```

and all the windows you open will be maximised. You can set maximus as an autostart app (the command is simply `maximus`).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to perform what [inLoveWithPython](https://askubuntu.com/users/52448/inlovewithpython) said earlier, then go to Edit > Preferences > Window Management and uncheck the box that says "save window positions on exit" and click the button that says "save window positions now."